# TYPO3: How to use disablePrependAtCopy in combination with allowLanguageSynchronization?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

My question refers to the default "assets"-TCA-field. For the assets-field `allowLanguageSynchronization` is set to 'true' and `disablePrependAtCopy` for sys_file_reference is active.

This configuration works as expected when the content element is translated for the first time. [Translate to XY] is not visible in the translated content element.

However, when I add another image to the content element for sys-lang 0 after the initial translation, [Translate to XY] is visible for sys-lang 1.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

> How can I stop TYPO3 from adding [Translate to XY] to the metadata fields?

*Configuration:*

Version: TYPO3 9.5.5

'allowLanguageSynchronization' is set to true:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['assets']['config']['behaviour']['allowLanguageSynchronization'] = true;
```

I also disabledPrependAtCopy for assets:

```
TCEMAIN.table.sys_file_reference {
    disablePrependAtCopy = 1
}
```

*What I tried:*

1. For sys-lang 0: Add image to a content element which uses the assets field (e.g. text-media).
2. Add metadata for image (e.g. title).
3. Translate content element to sys_lang 1 ([Translate to XY] is not visible as expected).
4. Go back to sys-lang 0: add a second image to content element and save the changes.
5. Switch to sys-lang 1: metadata of new file now contains [Translate to XY] -> How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You need another TCEMAIN setting here.
Try the following code

```
TCEMAIN {
    translateToMessage = 
}
```

if this does not work, maybe you can disable it by this code

```
TCEMAIN {
    translateToMessage > 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately, it does not work as expected in my case. That's the [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub4gxozkj8gb5pf/Result%20translatedMessage.png?dl=0).
The problem is caused by a bug, see [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87887#change-396804)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still not fixed. https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87887 is connected to TYPO3 v9, however changes in v10 were made. Even those changes do not work..

However, I was able to walk around the problem by **unset the l10n_mode** of the fields alternative, description and title.
Default it is set to *prefixLangTitle* and *exclude* would remove the field in the translations completely.

Therefore, unset (or probably set it to empty or an invalid value) does not add the prefix.